# metrics-server fails to start - metric-storage not ready?

Tags: kubernetes

Having a problem where the metric server is failing to start.  Initial deployment was 2021 (version v0.6.1), and worked for a couple years.  After a crash recovery, the metric server is failing to start with a TLS error in the logs.  I've tried a redeploy of the current (v0.6.3) and older versions (v0.6.1), and get the same issue.

Deployment status

```
kube-state-metrics-898575cdb-rwrsq         1/1     Running   0          23d     10.233.92.183   node3   <none>           <none>
metrics-server-68c5fc6c44-676zj            0/1     Running   0          7m37s   10.233.96.18    node2   <none>           <none>
```

I think the problem is with the metrics storage - after going through everything below, I found this when I probed the readyz condition

`[-]metric-storage-ready failed: reason withheld`

looking at logs says tls error, but I think thats a symptom, not the cause -

```
$ kubectl logs metrics-server-68c5fc6c44-676zj -nkube-system
Error from server: Get "https://10.0.92.31:10250/containerLogs/kube-system/metrics-server-68c5fc6c44-676zj/metrics-server": remote error: tls: internal error
```

Searching I found [Kubernetes metrics-server having SSL trouble](https://serverfault.com/questions/951848/kubernetes-metrics-server-having-ssl-trouble) from several years ago.  I verified that we were and are using the --kubelet-insecure-tls flag.

Pod description

```
$ kubectl describe deployment metrics-server -nkube-system
Name:                   metrics-server
Namespace:              kube-system
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 28 Mar 2023 11:37:53 -0400
Labels:                 k8s-app=metrics-server
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
Selector:               k8s-app=metrics-server
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  0 max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           k8s-app=metrics-server
  Service Account:  metrics-server
  Containers:
   metrics-server:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.6.1
    Port:       4443/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --secure-port=4443
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
      --kubelet-use-node-status-port
      --metric-resolution=15s
      --kubelet-insecure-tls
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     200Mi
    Liveness:     http-get https://:https/livez delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get https://:https/readyz delay=20s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
  Volumes:
   tmp-dir:
    Type:               EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:             
    SizeLimit:          <unset>
  Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   metrics-server-68c5fc6c44 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----               ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  34m                deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set metrics-server-6594d67d48 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  13m                deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set metrics-server-6594d67d48 to 0
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  13m                deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set metrics-server-68c5fc6c44 to 0
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  13m (x2 over 15m)  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set metrics-server-68c5fc6c44 to 1
```

Now, further searching lead to [Metrics-server is in CrashLoopBackOff with NEW install by rke](https://serverfault.com/questions/1074758/metrics-server-is-in-crashloopbackoff-with-new-install-by-rke)

In this, there is a check for the response of **livez** and **readyz**

Here is what I get -

```
$ time curl -k https://10.233.96.18:4443/livez
ok
real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.010s

$ time curl -k https://10.233.96.18:4443/readyz
[+]ping ok
[+]log ok
[+]poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers ok
[+]informer-sync ok
[+]poststarthook/max-in-flight-filter ok
[-]metric-storage-ready failed: reason withheld
[+]metadata-informer-sync ok
[+]shutdown ok
readyz check failed

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Now the question - **[-]metric-storage-ready failed: reason withheld**

What is that, and is that why its failing to deploy?